# Is there a better way to prevent same option selection in md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using `Angular Material` md-select control. My use case suggests to display a warning message to the user when he changes the options from dropdown. This works as a reminder that the currently visible data and selected options are not in sync.

However, I would like to display the message only when the user effectively changes the values (ignoring the case when he re-selects the same options).

Currently I have my changing logic in `md-on-close` and hence just expanding and collapsing shows the error message, which is not desirable.

Now, I am aware that I could move this logic from `md-`on-close`to a`$watch`on the`md-select` models and look for effective change there.

Also I could store last selected values in a service and can compare values on each `md-on-close`.

However, I do not want to use `$watch` as I believe it not to be the appropriate way of doing this. Adding and updating values in service seems like a redundant task.

So currently I am looking for a better way of comparing this. Is there any method in the library itself that I am mising, because it seems to be quite a simple and common use case for a control like `md-select`

Comment: Save the initial value of the field, and compare that value to the currently selected value in an `ng-show` - only show the message if the values differ

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use watch, you can simply use ng-change directive, like this:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="dropdownOptionChanged()">
```

And then handle the warning display in `dropdownOptionChanged()` function.

It will only trigger when user's selection has changed the model and won't trigger if the user selects the same option.